# Save to PNG changes colors

Tags: qgis, print-composer, color, png, save

I am trying to save this print composer as PNG

[image]

When I open the saved file, this is the result

[image]

The same thing happens if I save to pdf. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Do you have the images of the composer as separate layers, or did you change the single layer and added it to the composure? The print composer only exports the view of the current layer.

Comment: Yes... they are separate layers actually. Did not know that print composer can't export separate layers. Any idea how to go around this?

Comment: No, sorry I meant that if you use only 1 layer for the different images, the print composer exports only the current view of that layer.
If you have separate layers for all of the images you should not have the problem. Maybe make sure you are actually selecting the correct layer for each window?

Comment: I had 8 rasters loaded in QGIS. I was displaying one by one and adding a new map to the print composer.

Comment: Related to: [How to handle multiple map frames with different layers in one print layout?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45174/how-to-handle-multiple-map-frames-with-different-layers-in-one-print-layout)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The composer map windows don't automatically refresh when you update layers, but pull the latest view when you export. If you toggled each layer then added the map to canvas this could cause the problem described. If you refresh the canvas, does it change to look like the .png?

If so, toggle each layer as before, refresh the canvas and then lock the layers in for the corresponding map in the composer. This should then remain the same when you toggle a new layer and refresh. Once this is done for all layers, the image should export as expected.