Removing unnecessary layers in overview map in QGIS
How can I remove unnecessary layers in the overview map?
For example in the highlighted view, BMs must be removed.


Perhaps locking the layers is what you need - https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/330776/2856

I agree with previous. Lock the layer in the main map view and then remove the layers labels and then your overview map should have no labels. Then lock the over view map.

Using map theme is the way to go : https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#configuring-map-themes

Set Layer / Label scale visibilities to hide them at small scales

A simple solution:
You go to your main project view (not the layout view where you generate the map) and enable only the layers or groups you want to display.
Then go to your map again. Click your map on the item list. If it still displays the layers, click on the refresh button under "Item Properties". Then put a checkmark at Layers > "Lock layers". Now, only the current layers are displayed, even if you add new layers to your project or if you display the layers again.

Thank you for your point I believe that will be useful!
I could manage the visibility of the specific layers by scale visibility which I  suddenly remembered from ArcGIS

I agree with the solution suggested by @J.R.

Create map themes,main_layout and overview, in the QGIS window.

In the layout window, insert two maps, and then go to item properties 
tick the "Follow map theme" and select the theme (main_layout, overview) for each map.


