# Translating one raster's contents closer to another’s with each at different scales using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, layers, overlay, united-states

I'm working with multiple raster images, each in the Albers Equal Area Conic projection: one of the mainland US, one of Alaska, and one of Hawaii.

I'd like to translate the Hawaii layer to be closer to mainland US, reduce its size, and then output the resultant image as a `.tiff` file.

Is this is possible, is there a way to do it in QGIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming QGIS supports data frames you could use three of them with different extents (for contiguous states, Alaska and Hawaii ) on a layout, and then export that layout to a TIFF file.

Comment: Looks like the data frame concept is available in QGIS, so I'll try that: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45174/how-to-handle-multiple-map-frames-with-different-layers-in-one-print-layout